# groovy generics: calling method on super class. Type erasure

Tags: generics, groovy, super, type-erasure

I cannot understand why the following Groovy code won't compile

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class GenericTest<T extends String> extends TreeSet<T> {

    public boolean add2(T key) {
        return super.add(key)
    }
}
```

It tells me

> [Static type checking] - Cannot call
>   java.util.TreeSet#add(java.lang.Object ) with arguments
>   [java.lang.String ]

I understand it must be something related to type erasure, but I can't figure it out.

the similar java code compiles without problems

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class GenericTest2<T extends String> extends TreeSet<T> {

    public boolean add2(T val){
        return super.add(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: That might be a bug... What version of Groovy are you using?  If it's 2.1.2, I'd ask this question on the groovy user mailing list

Comment: [It might be this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5891)

Comment: it's 2.1.3, I'm not sure it's the same bug ...